# Change Dropdown Icon

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to change the default `caret` icon to dots (something like the below image) in dropdown. I tried with `::after` but it didn't work.

[image: droddown]

```
library(bslib)
library(shiny)

ui <- function(request) { 
  
  bootstrapPage(
    navbarPage(
      id = "dir",
      theme = bs_theme(
        version = 3,
        bootswatch = "yeti"
      ),
      title = "Mobile Testing", 
      windowTitle = "Mobile Testing", 
      collapsible = TRUE,
      
      header =  tags$head(tagList(tags$style(HTML('

.selectize-control.single .selectize-input, .selectize-control.single .selectize-input input {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: darkslategrey;
    color: #fff;
}

.selectize-input::after{background-color:#fff;height:15px;mask-image:url(assets/icons/dots.svg);width:15px;-webkit-mask-image:url(assets/icons/dots.s
vg)}                                                  
                                                  '
      ))
      )),
      
      ## First navbarMenu
      navbarMenu(
        title = "Menu #1", 
        tabPanel(title = "Tab 1", 
                 selectizeInput("variable", "Variable:",
                                c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                                  "Transmission" = "am",
                                  "Gears" = "gear"),
                                multiple = FALSE,
                                options = list(
                                  readOnly = TRUE, 
                                  onDelete = I("function() { return false }")
                                ))
                 )
    )
  ) )
  
}

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 
  ## empty server
})

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**SVG Path of dots**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" style="fill: #343434">
    <path d="M50 80a6.982 6.982 0 01-4.95-2.05L2.05 34.952a7.003 7.003 0 119.904-9.904L50 63.095l38.045-38.046a7.003 7.003 0 019.903 0 7 7 0 010 9.904L54.95 77.951A6.982 6.982 0 0150 80z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few details

1. Your svg is not dots but arrows, here is a correct svg example

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="ellipsis-h" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" class="svg-inline--fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-w-16 fa-2x"><path fill="currentColor" d="M328 256c0 39.8-32.2 72-72 72s-72-32.2-72-72 32.2-72 72-72 72 32.2 72 72zm104-72c-39.8 0-72 32.2-72 72s32.2 72 72 72 72-32.2 72-72-32.2-72-72-72zm-352 0c-39.8 0-72 32.2-72 72s32.2 72 72 72 72-32.2 72-72-32.2-72-72-72z" class=""></path></svg>
```

2. Please `addResourcePath` if you want to use any local resources if the files are not inside the `www` folder of current working directory. My code below uses the current working directory and I set the prefix to `myfiles`. `addResourcePath("myfiles", "./")`, in your case, set `addResourcePath("your_prefix", "./assets/icons")`.
3. Some problems in your CSS, I fixed.

```r
library(bslib)
library(shiny)
addResourcePath("myfiles", "./")
ui <- function(request) { 
    
    bootstrapPage(
        navbarPage(
            id = "dir",
            theme = bs_theme(
                version = 3,
                bootswatch = "yeti"
            ),
            title = "Mobile Testing", 
            windowTitle = "Mobile Testing", 
            collapsible = TRUE,
            
            header =  tags$head(tagList(tags$style(HTML('

            .selectize-control.single .selectize-input, .selectize-control.single .selectize-input input {
                cursor: pointer;
                background: darkslategrey;
                color: #fff;
            }

            .selectize-control.single .selectize-input:after {
                height:15px;
                width:15px;
                content:url(myfiles/dots.svg);
                border: none;
            }                                                  
            '
            ))
            )),

## First navbarMenu
navbarMenu(
    title = "Menu #1", 
    tabPanel(title = "Tab 1", 
             selectizeInput("variable", "Variable:",
                            c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                              "Transmission" = "am",
                              "Gears" = "gear"),
                            multiple = FALSE,
                            options = list(
                                readOnly = TRUE, 
                                onDelete = I("function() { return false }")
                            ))
    )
)
        ) )
    
}

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 
    ## empty server
})

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]